# Detect When a file is accessed/read with java

Tags: java, windows, file, io, notifications

What I am trying to accomplish is detect whenever a file is read. 
Basically, it is going to be a sort of on-access scanner.

After searching google and SO, the only things I come up with are detecting file modifications (file change notification) using Jnotify, java.nio.file etc.

Is this currently possible in java, if not, is it possible in windows?
Does windows give any way of accessing this? If yes, I do not mind coding a library in C or C++.
I would love a cross-platform solution, but a windows only solution would also be great.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look to Java 7 & NIO. See [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) for more details.

Comment: I have read that already. As I said before, NIO seems only to give notifications on create, delete, modify only. No read notification.

Comment: My bad.  I did not read your question carefully enough.  Considering deleting my answer, but will refrain for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly  the reason JNotify and other such libraries exists. For instance, JNotify uses WinAPI mechanisms to check for file notifications, which you would have to use anyway if you dediced to write a library.

Use JNotify or any other Java library that provides file notification services.

Comment: "
JNotify java API
JNotify is a java library that allow java application to listen to file system events, such as:

    File created
    File modified
    File renamed
    File deleted
"

There is no notification in these libraries for file read. but thanks for the term "winapi" it might help. I am new to OS development.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Hm, if you want to be notified in particular when somebody reads a chunk of file you may have hard time doing that. I am not sure whether it's even possible...

Comment: any idea how antivirus software make on access scanners?

Comment: Hm, they usually closely integrate with OS. A lot of things are possible at the kernel level and not in the userland:)